# User jquery with css atributes

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible insert more of one attributes in jQuery function with CSS? For me, it's necessary to insert more than one change in CSS.

For example, if I want change the width and height, I can do this:

```
<script>$(this).css("height","200");</script>
```

But if I want insert in the same width also and height?

I try do this with separated functions and works but inside no see examples for no need open new function each time

Answer (score 3):

Yes :

```
$(this).css({ "height" : "200", "width" : "200" });
```

Specifically, look at this part of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation! This should give you a fair amount of resources.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

$(this).css({ "height" : x, "width" : y });